# Removable Storage encryption and usage

Tags: hard-drive, encryption

So, I will buy an WD External Hard Disk, and I wonder how can I encrypt it, and if I can use it on another OS, like Windows or MAC OSX

Comment: You could possibly use [Truecrypt.](https://sourceforge.net/projects/truecrypt/) There appears to be some differences of opinion as to whether it's safe to use now that it's out of development, however [this too may pass](https://www.grc.com/misc/truecrypt/truecrypt.htm)

Comment: @ElderGeek good to know, but about using the HDD on every OS how can I do that? Or do I need to make partitions with different formats.

Comment: It appears that Truecrypt is available for MAC OSX, Windows, and Linux. If that's your definition of every OS than it's certainly possible. There's a user guide available [here](https://www.grc.com/misc/truecrypt/TrueCrypt%20User%20Guide.pdf) Sorry, I can't test this for you and give you a definitive answer but hopefully this will help you [answer your own question](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/111/should-one-answer-ones-own-question)

Comment: @ElderGeek No, no, no, my bad you misunderstood, I was asking about using the HDD on other OS but Linux, not Truecrypt.

Comment: My untested assumption is that as long as the underlying file system is supported by all the operating systems in question it shouldn't be a problem. This likely means that your limited to FAT32 or perhaps [ExFAT](https://www.howtogeek.com/235596/whats-the-difference-between-fat32-exfat-and-ntfs/) for a file system as both Windows and OSX are somewhat limited in terms of supported filesystems.